# Custom conversions, deduction guide, C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Извините, не знаю, как точнее сформулировать вопрос (иначе бы получилось найти ответ в гугле). Есть такая вещь, как определённые пользователем приведения типов данных. Но есть ещё кое-что: можно заставить компилятор считать всякое вхождение `const char*` за `std::string`. (Для тех же deduction guides, например.) Делается это в одну строку немудрёными словами. Вот только я не помню и не могу найти, какими. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Поясните, что значит "считать всякое вхождение `const char*` за `std::string`". Если переменная объявлена как `const char*`, то она и будет `const char*`.

Comment: `std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, const char *>, std::string, T>`?

Comment: @maestro в тех случаях, когда компилятор сам определяет тип шаблонной подстановки: `std::vector vs("abc")`. Здесь `"abc"` будет `const char*`, однако можно что-то сделать, чтобы в таких случаях `"abc"` было `std::string` (работает не только для `const char*` и `std::string`, беру их для примера)

Comment: По-моему, это можно сделать только если есть перегрузка функции (в том числе конструктора) для `std::string`. Тогда `const char*` будет автоматически преобразовываться в `std::string`, так как у `std::string` есть неявный конструктор, который принимает `const char*`. Даже если написать что-то вроде `template<typename T, typename Allocator> vector(const char *) -> vector<string, Allocator>;`, всё равно у вектора не появится конструктор, принимающий `const char*`.

Comment: Если хочется сократить запись конструктора строки, можно воспользоваться литеральным оператором: `#include <string> using namespace std::string_literals; vector a({"abc"s, "def"s});`

Comment: @maestro спасибо! Хорошего дня

Answer (score 0):

Это называется custom deduction guide и он для встроенных классов не работает. Пример использования для самописных:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
  
  T data;

  S(T x) : data(x) {}
};


S(const char*) -> S<std::string>;

S s("abc"); //decltype(s.data) - std::string
```