# Custom deduction guide для std::классов

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Изучаю вопрос о **custom** **deduction guides**. Вижу примеры, в которых его применяют для своих классов:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
T data;

  S(T x) : data(x) {}
};


S(const char*) -> S<std::string>;

S s("abc"); //decltype(s.data) - std::string
```

Когда пробую провернуть такое для библиотечных типов, не выходит:

```
std::vector(const char*) -> std::vector<std::string>
```

Компилятор говорит:

‘std::vector(const char*)-> std::vector >’ should have been declared inside ‘std’

Можно ли это обойти какими-нибудь шаблонными трюками?

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке же указывается, как исправить эту проблему. Однако модификация поведения  стандартной библиотеки обычно не допускается в принципе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, такое читерство — формально запрещенное (добавлять что-то к пространству имен `std` запрещено (или категорически не рекомендуется, точно не помню...)):

```
namespace std {
    vector(const char*) -> vector<string>;
}
```

Comment: В [смежном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1485028/3380) вы хотели, чтобы было можно писать так: `std::vector vs("abc")`. Полагаю, (вы этого не уточнили) вы хотели, чтобы вектор инициализировался одним элементом типа `std::string`. Но данный ответ не даёт возможности такой записи. Так поясните же конкретно, чего вы хотите?

Comment: Harry, позволил себе поправить, вы это имели в виду? Правило дедукции работает, но замысел автора всё равно не реализован. Запись `std::vector vs("abc")` даёт ошибку: `no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector [with _Tp=std::string, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::string>]" matches the argument list argument types are: (const char [4])`

Comment: @maestro Спасибо за дополнения и уточнения. Я имел в виду, что формально ошибка компиляции будет преодолена, но сам метод преодоления неверный... Что касается *семантики* — это уже совсем другой вопрос, который должен быть задан иначе...